# Conditional Formatting of items in a Combox

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, viewmodel, wpfdatagrid

Currently I'm in a team building a datagrid that contains data coming from a viewmodel. We are using reactive-ui and each "row" in the datagrid is represented by a viewmodel class that inherits from "ReactiveObject".

There are 2 properties in the viewmodel tha tI'm interested in to fill a combobox in each row. A collection of *PossibleScales* and the *DefaultScale*. The *PossibleScales* are loaded into the combobox and the *DefaultScale* is used to set the selecteditem to the *DefaultScale*. The *DefaultScale* is always contained by the *DefaultScale* collection. What I want to achieve is that any non-default scale in the combobox is formatted in italics. So I created a style that invokes a *IMultiValueConverter*. so, I need to give this IMultiValueConverter 2 parameters, the current scale (from the collection of PossibleScales and the DefaultScale.

Here's the XAML that we have to fill the combobox with all the items in the list of PossibleScales (I have the same for EditingElementStyle):

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
       <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=PossibleScales}"  />
       <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource Measeurementscale}"></Setter>
   </Style>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

The **Measeurementscale** *StaticResource* is defined as a style in the resources section of the control.

```
<Style x:Key="Measeurementscale" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="FontStyle">
       <Setter.Value>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NonDefaultScaleToItalicConverter}">
              <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="DataContext"/>
          </MultiBinding>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As you can see, the current value of the comboboxitem is passed to the **IMultiValueConverter**, so that's great. But now I'm wondering how I can pass the DefaultScale (which is a property of the viewmodel and defined as DataContext for the control) to this converter as well. I have not been able to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FindAncestor` to get the parent control where this data context is set, and bind to it. For example:

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}"
         Path="DataContext.DefaultScale" />
```

Comment: I don't know why, but FontStyle is not working. Opacity is, so I use this instead. The most important thing for me was to have a visual clue for non default scales, your answer helped a lot. So I have achieved my goal: conditional formatting of items in a combobox